# Need to call a PowerShell-file inside SoapUI with Groovy

Tags: powershell, groovy, soapui

I need to call a PowerShell file inside SoapUI with a Groovy script.

This is what I've tried (that doesn't work):

```
def testprojectDir = context.expand('${projectDir}')

def fileName = "test.ps" 

def file1 = new File(testprojectDir + '/Testdata///' + fileName );

def powerShellCommand = file1

def shellCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile  -Command \"${powerShellCommand}\""

def process = shellCommand.execute()

process.waitFor()
```

PowerShell code in "test.ps" is as follows:
"Some text..." | Out-File C:\temp\filename1.txt -encoding ascii

Any suggestions how I can get Groovy to work with PowerShell?

Comment: when you say "doesn't work", what does it do?

Comment: Hi, I mean I can't execute the ps-script.The ps-script doesn't create in this case a file. From SoapUI Groovy script I get Script-result: 0. Which means en error.

Comment: I got it to work. My bad, wrong filename should be ps1 instead of ps :-)